# I have used 'code .' command to open vs code in ubuntu on windows 10. But It didn't work

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

> ~$ code .

While running the above cmd, the following errors come along.

> Command 'code' not found, did you mean:
>
> command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.1build1)   command
> 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2)   command 'ode' from deb
> plotutils (2.6-10build1)   command 'node' from deb nodejs
> (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1)   command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
>
> Try: sudo apt install

How to fix this?

Comment: How did you install VSCode?

Comment: It looks like you installed vscode in windows instead of linux, isn't it?

Comment: If you are trying to start Windows VSCode in wsl2, you can define an alias : `alias code='"/c/Users/your-windows-user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe"'`, then `code .`

Comment: @user17732522 I have downloaded it from `https://code.visualstudio.com/download`

Comment: @JuanR I have installed vs code in windows 10 because I have windows os

Comment: @Philippe how and where to define them?

Comment: Put in $HOME/.bashrc if you use bash.

Comment: @Philippe I have changed to `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/ppant/AppData/Local/Programs/MicrosoftVSCode/Code.exe`  Still don't work

Comment: it works in window shell but not in ubuntu shell

Comment: -bash: /C/Users/PRASANT PANT/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: No such file or directory @Philippe

Comment: In your ubuntu shell, run `df -k`. You might have to add `/mnt` to make it : `alias code='"/mnt/c/Users/your-windows-user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe"'`